# 8x8 div matrix onclick effectivization

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, matrix, 2d

I would like to have an 8x8 matrix where I can click on each square and the color will change, for use in a project.

I have made a 2d array and the entire 8x8 "board" but now I want to change to color on click, although the only way I can think of is through heavy code, for example writing div[row][column] 64 times...

```
var div = new Array(8);
for(var i = 0; i<8; i++){
div[i] = new Array(8)
}


for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
    div[i][j] = document.createElement("div");
    div[i][j].style.width = "50px";
    div[i][j].style.height = "50px";
    div[i][j].style.backgroundColor = "white";
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(div[i][j]);
}
var jump = document.createElement("br");
document.getElementById("container").appendChild(jump);
}

div[0][0].onclick = function(){
if(div[0][0].style.backgroundColor == "white"){
    div[0][0].style.backgroundColor = "red"
    d00 = 1
}
else{div[0][0].style.backgroundColor = "white"
d00 = 0
}
}
```

I don't wish to write the above 64 times, surely there must be a better way.

```
#container {
margin: auto;
width:400px;
height:400px;
}
#container div {
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:top;
outline: 1px solid black
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, there is a better way.
Inside the for-loop you're already setting important properties of your DIVs. It's the perfect place to attach an **click** eventListener whose callback function will handle the color switching.

Modify the for-loop like this:

```
var divElement;
for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
    divElement = document.createElement("div");
    divElement.style.width = "50px";
    divElement.style.height = "50px";
    divElement.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    divElement.addEventListener("click", changeColor);
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(divElement);
  }
```

and use this function to actually change the color:

```
function changeColor(e) {
  if (e.target.style.backgroundColor == "white") {
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = "red"
    d00 = 1
  } else {
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = "white"
    d00 = 0
  }
}
```

*e.target* refers to the object that triggered the event.
Forgive me, I don't know the purpose of *d00*.

Comment: Thanks, the purpose is for later, i am going to run a websocket with my raspberry pi and a physical 8x8 led matrix.

Comment: Although im getting an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '8' of undefined
    at 8x8.js:24";                                                                                                               js:24 is div[i][j].addEventListener("click", changeColor);

Comment: Hehe, yeah, that's because of the div[i][j] and the value 8 which is stored in all of the arrays element. I refnied my answer to take care of that though I must say the answer provided by EJC is the even more elegant way of doing this since you'd just need a single eventListener.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach the onclick event to the parent container and use event.target to get the div which triggered the event:

```
document.getElementById("container").onclick = function(event){
  if(event.target.style.backgroundColor == "white"){
    event.target.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
  else{
    event.target.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  }
}
```

Comment: How could i get information on what div[i][j] was clicked?

Comment: @Maiki event.target will be the innermost element that caused the onclick event. In this case, that will be the small div representing a square on your grid.

Comment: made a function that i run for every onclick event:                                            function truedivs(){
    for(var i = 0; i<8; i++){
      for(var j = 0; j<8; j++){
        if(div[i][j].value == 1){console.log(i + " " +j)}
      }
    }
  }

Comment: @Maiki I would just change that if statement to if(div[i][j].style.backgroundColor === "red")